# Versioned Custom Post Type (Not the same as revisions)

Tags: custom-post-types, filters, url-rewriting, child-pages

I want to create a special custom post type with a url format as follows

site_root/post_slug[/post_name[/version_number]]

site_root/post_slug: 
points to a list of posts i.e. post_name

site_root/post_slug/post_name: 
points to the latest version (not permalink)

site_root/post_slug/post_name/version_number: 
points to the specific version number

In the admin Menu it would have

post_name1
  - Version 1
  - Version 2
  - etc.
post_name2
  - Version 1
  - Version 2
  - etc.

sample urls

i.e. for licenses, with the gpl as a license all 3 versions: 
site_root/license/gpl/1.0
site_root/license/gpl/2.0
site_root/license/gpl/3.0

i.e. for software information/download page for python2 (2.5, 2.6 and 2.7): 
site_root/downloads/python2/2.5
site_root/downloads/python2/2.6
site_root/downloads/python2/2.7
site_root/software/python2/2.5
site_root/software/python2/2.6
site_root/software/python2/2.7

in these example site_root/license/gpl would point to site_root/license/gpl/3.0 and site_root/{software|downloads}/python would point to site_root/{software|downloads}/python/2.7
site_root/software/python2/2.7

I have been able to find anything of this because all my searches end up returning results about handling revisions.

Example of what I want see pypi

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/numpy/
Points to news version
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/numpy/1.13.0
Points to specific version 1.13.0 (Currently newest)
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/numpy/1.11.0
Points to specific version 1.11.0 (Older Version)

I'm currently working with my own plugin creating the post-type by calling
register_post_type, I've all ready use this to create a custom post type plugin, what I don't know how to manage is the displaying multiple versions like I want to for my current project.

**Update #1**

After some further research I've found information on endpoints which looks similar to what I want but not exactly the same.

Endpoints register something like &version={version_string} to be rewritten from post_slug/'version'/version_string, i.e. using this it would produce the structure site_root/post_slug[/post_name[/'version'/version_number]]. See https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_endpoint and https://make.wordpress.org/plugins/2012/06/07/rewrite-endpoints-api/. Further more based on the second link this results in

```
$rewrite[ "([^/]+)/{$query_var}(/(.*))?/?$" ] = "index.php?name=$1&{$query_var}=$3"
```

being executed in WP_Rewrite::generate_rewrite_rules().

This would suggest that I need to alter the rewrite rules for my custom post type such that it dose something along the lines of

```
$rewrite[ "{$custom_post_slug}/([^/]+)/(/({$version_pattern})?/?$" ] = "index.php?name=$1&{$query_var}=$3"
```

I've also found the hook https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/$permastruct_rewrite_rules, which seams like it would allow me to alter the rewrite rules for my post type, however the documentation doesn't explain how this hook operates nor can I find the exact structure of the rule I would require.